# Rectangle trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

[image: pic]

The angle between the 2 diagonals in a rectangle is 66°38' and it's surface area is 33 cm2. What are the lenghts of the rectangle's sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both opposite triangles inside the rectangle are congruent, and since all four half diagonals are equal, say of length $\;\ell\;$ , you have

$$33=S_{Rec.}=2\left(\ell\sin66.38^\circ+\ell\sin(180-66.38)^\circ\right)=4\ell\sin66.38^\circ=3.6649\ell$$

I'll leave it to you to calculate the sides using $\;\ell\;$, but observe that $\;2\ell\;$ is both of the big diagonals' length, so you'll get:

$$\begin{cases}a^2+b^2=\ell^2\\{}\\ab=3.6649\ell\end{cases}$$

All you have to do is to solve the above system.